# Use preg_split for all special characters

Tags: php, regex

I want to split a String everytime a special character is found.

I did this :

```
preg_split("[\\W]", $str);
```

But this will still allow underscore (and maybe more?)

Is it possible to just say allow a-z A-Z and digits and split on anything that is not one of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just answered your question:

```
preg_split('~[^a-z0-9]~i', $str);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU6tO6/3)

The `[^a-z0-9]` *negated* character class matches any character other than `a-z` (and `A-Z` due to the `i` modifier) and other than a digit (defined with `0-9`).

Another way is with using POSIX `[:alnum:]` character class inside a negated character class:

```
'~[^[:alnum:]]~'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU6tO6/1)

Note that it is easier to use single char regex delimiters rather than paired ones, my favorite being `~`. It is rarely used in regex patterns, and thus I do not have to escape too much in my patterns.

Comment: Very detailed answer! I'm pretty new to regex so I wasn't sure if it was possible

Comment: Here is a [link to the Web resource dwelling on **negated character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).